# how to publish a web service which contains .WSDL file

Tags: web-services, wsdl, publish

how can I publish a wcf project web service so that it contains .WSDL file with it.
I need the .wsdl file to call from a java base client.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the .WSDL file. You need the service to expose metadata. See [`<serviceMetadata>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731317.aspx).